# What is causing this heap buffer overflow?

Tags: c, debugging, malloc, overflow, heap-memory

[This is the error in the terminal that I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TvVZ.png)

This is my code, what exactly is the issue that is causing this heap buffer overflow. To give context this code is a Run Length Encoder that I am programming in C. I am fairly new to it so I am still learning the ropes, but as far as syntax goes it is all correct anyways here is the code.

```
char* compress(char* str){
    
    int len = strlen(str);

    char build= (char*)malloc(2*len);
    

    int i;

    for(i=0; i<len;i++){

            int count =1;

            while ((i<len-1) && (str[i]==str[i+1])){

                count++;
                i++;
            }

            strncat(build, &str[i], 1);
            //delete later
            printf("%s\n", build);

            char *c = count+ "0";

            strcat(build, c);
            //delete later
            printf("%s\n", build);
    }

    return build;

    free(build);

}

int compareLength(int str1, int str2){

    if(str1>str2){

        return 0;

    } else {

        return 1;
    }
}

int containsDigit(char* input){

    int i;
    int len = strlen(input);
    int isDigit=0;

    for(i=0;i<len;i++){

        if(isdigit(input[i])==0)

            isDigit++;
    }

    if(isDigit>0){

        return 1;
    }else{

        return 0;
    }

}


int main(int argc, char** argv){

    char *input = argv[1];

    int inputLen = (strlen(input));
    int compressLen = (strlen(compress(input)));

    if(containsDigit(input)==1){

        printf("%s\n", "error");

    } else {


        if(compareLength(inputLen, compressLen)==1){

            printf("%s\n", input);      
        }else{

            printf("%s\n", compress(input));
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: One possible problem: [Don't cast the result of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). And one definitive problem: `malloc` doesn't initialize the memory it allocates, leaving it *indeterminate*. All string functions requires that it's *null-terminated*.

Comment: And another definitive problem: `char *c = count+ "0"` That doesn't make sense, and `c` will point somewhere invalid.

Comment: OT: `containsDigit` is not very efficient. Hint: once you've encountered a non digit character, you're done.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I know 'containsDigit' is really inefficient I just need to add 'break;' and I should be good

Comment: @KushPatel it's even simpler. Hint: you can drop the `if(isDigit>0)` test alltogether.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude how would I go about converting an int, (any number from 0 to infinity, but realistically probably less than 100k) to a char. I read on this forum that all you have to do is add "0" but I learned that it only works for 0 through 9 not above.

Comment: `char build= (char*)malloc(2*len);` `build` is of type `char` you need `char *`

Comment: @Jabberwocky right I can just return 1 if that condition is met. Thanks for the catch

Comment: A generic `int` value to a string? `snprintf(dest, sizeof dest, "%d", int_value);` A single *digit* to a single character? `char c = int_digit + '0';` (note difference in type and quotes).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude is it `snprintf` or `sprintf`

Comment: If you're 100% certain that the destination buffer will fit the string, use `sprintf`. Otherwise use `snprint` to prevent buffer overflows.